# Can I obtain two random variables from one?

Tags: probability, random-variables

For instance, if I have one die, I roll it and see if the result is even, and whether it is more than 3. Thus I can simulate two tosses of a coin, but they are not independent, as there is only one even number below the median while two above. I cannot think of any way to obtain a uniform distribution of two coins from one cubic dice. *(This may have something to do with placing 6 things into 4 bins uniformly.)* I can, however, obtain a uniform distribution of two coin tosses with a tetrahedron trivially.

Suppose then that I have a disc with a chosen point on the continuous edge, and I rotate this disc randomly against a static mark. The arc between the mark and the point gives me a random real number from 0 to 1. Can I use it to place a point on a square with uniform distribution? Practically, I see that I can use a mapping from the arc to some iteration of a space filling curve *(such as the Peano curve)* to uniformly pick one arbitrarily small tile from a square lattice tesselation. But it seems that any non-uniform continuous distribution, such as a 2-dimensional normal distribution, would be very hard to achieve. *(One way to go may be to define a very particular piecewise mapping from the arc to the curve.)*

What kinds of distributions can I obtain this way? Can I obtain any number of independent random variables, either discrete or continuous, from a single random variable? Is this a right way of thinking?

Comment: Feel free to edit the tags!

Comment: You can simulate two fair coins with one die as follows: 1 = HH, 2 = HT, 3 = TH, 4 = TT, 5 or 6 = reroll. With probability 1, you won't roll forever. Does this satisfy you? On the other hand, it's pretty clear that you can't simulate two fair coins with a single roll of a fair die, since 1/4 is not a multiple of 1/6...

Comment: Going from [uniform to Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) is well known.  To go from one random real $x \in [0,1)$ to two random reals $(y,z) \in [0,1)^2$, theoretically you can look at the binary expansion of $x$, and use alternate digits for $y$ and $z$?  It's not a continuous mapping but who cares.  There is no need to use a space filling curve (which maintains continuity).  Of course, in practice you have limited resolution, and if your original $x$ is in $N$ bits each of $y, z$ will have only $N/2$ bits.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been indicated in the comments, you can obtain $m$ numbers uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ from one such number by considering the binary representations formed by its binary digits numbered $k+nm$, where for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ the digits for all $n\in\mathbb N$ are concatenated to obtain the $k$-th random number. You can then transform these uniformly distributed random numbers e.g. to normally distributed ones.